# One vs. multiple repositories with Azure Mobile Client SDK - architectural guidance

Tags: c#, android, azure, mobile, xamarin

I am writing a Xamarin Android app and using Azure Mobile SDK.  My data model has Users with Lists with ListItems.  Since users can have multiple Lists and Lists could be shared, there is a Many-to-Many relationship between Users and Lists managed through a UserLists entity.  So User -> UserLists <- Lists <- ListItems. 
On a given device, only current user's Lists will be loaded.

So I have 4 entities on the back-end and I have 4 entities on the client.  Sync is set up such that it only pulls current user's lists (and associated list items).  Now all 4 entities are managed by one repository (ListRepository) since these entities are so interrelated.  Is that a good pattern?  With 4 entities, its already getting out of hand (only 2 are "updateable" - Lists and ListItems).  If this model were to grow, the repository would become quite bloated.

Alternatively, having multiple repositories (one for each entity) and grouping them under one service would be what one would expect but that would mean a lot of trips back and forth between the service and various repositories to capture the interdependent entities.  Also, how would referential integrity be handled unless they are all related to the same SyncContext?

Comment: What you mean by "repositories" and "entities"? What is the relationship between your list and your entities and repository? Is this a back-end problem or a client problem? Or is this just a Database issue?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, this is a client question.

I am building an MVVM Xamarin app.  In the Core PCL project, I have ViewModels, Models (a.k.a entities), Services and Repositories.  ViewModels talk to Services which in turn talk to Repositories which use Azure Mobile Client SDK to talk to a Mobile App Rest API (to be placed in Azure at some point in time).  Users, Lists and ListItems are my Models and there is a one to many relationship between them as described above.

I have a separate Repository to deal with User model and a separate to deal with List and ListItem.  It seems like I couldn't commit List without committing User but user was in a different repository so there was a problem.

I have resolved it by basing both repository on the same static MobileServiceClient and MobileServiceSQLiteStore.

Based on the above, it seems to me that if the database is implemented with referential integrity then either a) entities have to be committed from the client to the back-end in a specific order (have not provien this) or b) client has to use the same MobileServiceClient and MobileServiceSQLiteStore for all entities with relationships.